# If I have parent and a child inside, and a css rule for the parent and a a generic css, why does the generic css rule take precedence?

Tags: html, css

I have the html and css as follows

```css
.slide {
  font-family: "Titillium Web";
}

h4 {
  font: normal 500 19px / 25px "Roboto";
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <h4>title</h4>
</div>
```

The css rule of `h4` overrides the css rule of `.slide`. The font-family of the "title" is "Roboto". Since more specific css selector, in this case, class name should take precedence. Can anyone explain this to me?